# Is there a hotkey to Search Wikipedia for "x"?

Tags: keyboard, spotlight

This is a question about keyboard shortcuts. I think it's quite cool that you can put a word into the spotlight and one of the options is to search Wikipedia for it, but to get that functionality takes a lot of typing or mouse movement. Is there a fast way to do it?

Example: `CMD-Space` opens the spotlight, I type `tidal basin`. About 30 files, most irrelevant appear, and at the bottom is the wikipedia search. I can use the mouse to click on it, or I can hit `ctrl-n` many times to get there and then `return`. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default setup for Spotlight, Search Wikipedia is the second to last option, Spotlight Preferences being the last option. You could invoke Spotlight, press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> (or End if you have a full size keyboard with that key) then up and Enter.

Very little hand pivoting is necessary to accomplish this.

Comment: It's not bad, but I'm trying to avoid leaving home row at all. One idea that should work, but doesn't, is to hit `ctrl-p` twice to loop back to the bottom of the menu, but they seem to have disabled this.

Comment: Other options: Always use a browser. If you use Chrome, you can set up a custom search engine for Wikipedia, type `wp`, hit tab, type in the name of the article, enter. Alfred has a quickly selectable `search wikipedia for 'x'` option, as do many other Spotlight replacements.